# How to set Word doc page layout to two columns from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ms-word

How to set the Word doc page layout normal to 2 columns from MATLAB,

```
File='C:\Users\ies\Documents\MATLAB\test.docx'; %use full path 
[pth,name,ext]=fileparts(file); 
w=Word(file,true); %create document and make visible

addText(w,'Introduction','Heading 1',2); %create a heading, 2 spaces after 
addText(w,recognizedText); %add some text 
newline(w,6); %6 newlines 
pic=sprintf('%s/fig.png',pth); 

saveAs(w,file);
```

Above code saves text in a normal mode Word file, but I need two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Word` function is not a standard MATLAB function. Without providing details of where it has come from it's impossible to say for sure what its return value `w` is or how to interact with it. However, since the other non-standard functions seem to be treating it like a Word [`Document`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff822963.aspx) object, let's assume it's a COM interface to one of these.

In this case, you can set the number of columns to two using:

```
w.ActiveWindow.Selection.Sections.First.PageSetup.TextColumns.SetCount(2)
```